# possible to do Func<T1>(T2 param) where T1: Foo<T> and T2 is the T in Foo<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a screen manager for a game where I should be able to open the screens through said manager using a controller classes

I have this:

```
public interface IScreenController { }

public class UIScreen<T> where T : IScreenController
{
  public void Open(T controller) { }
}

public class ScreenManager
{
   public T GetScreen<T>()
   {
    //some screen getter method here
   }

   public void Open<T, J>(J controller) where T : UIScreen<J> where J : IScreenController
   {
     var screen = GetScreen<T>();
     screen.Open(controller);
   }
}

public class MyScreenController : IScreenController { }

public class OtherScreenController: IScreenController { };

public class MyScreen : UIScreen<MyScreenController> { }
```

and currently, i can make it work with this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public ScreenManager Manager;

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      Manager.Open<MyScreen, MyScreenController>(new MyScreenController());
   }
}
```

is it possible to do only `Manager.Open<MyScreen>(Controller)` while keeping enforcing the parameter?
I know i can do `Open<T>(IScreenController controller) where T: UIScreen`, but that would allow me to put any screen controller as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're setting yourself up for a world of heartache here trying to use generics like this. Once you're trying to constrain the types you should begin to ask yourself if it's better to just provide function overloads.

I know you've given us abbreviated code, but instead of:

```
public interface IScreenController { }

public class UIScreen<T> where T : IScreenController
{
    public void Open(T controller) { }
}
```

Why not just put the `Open` function in the interface? Then you can ditch `UIScreen` altogether, or if you really need it to implement some functionality that would make inheritance worthwhile then you could make `UIScreen` an abstract class, like:

```
public interface IScreenController
{ 
    public void Open(IScreenController controller) { }
}

public abstract class UIScreen : IScreenController
{
    public void Open(IScreenController controller) { // functionality goes here }
}
```

Another thing you could do is to specify the type as a constructor in your inheritance chain, like instead of what you wrote here:

```
public class UIScreen<T> where T : IScreenController
{
  public void Open(T controller) { }
}

public class MyScreenController : IScreenController { }

public class MyScreen : UIScreen<MyScreenController> { }
```

You could make `UIScreen` take an `IScreenController` as part of the constructor argument, and you could pass that when a subclass is constructed, like the following:

```
public class UIScreen
{
    protected IScreenController screenController;
    public UIScreen(IScreenController screenController)
    { 
        this.screenController = screenController;
    }
}

public class MyScreenController : IScreenController { }

public class MyScreen : UIScreen
{
    public MyScreen() : base(new MyScreenController()) { }
}
```

then you can do whatever needs doing from your `protected IScreenController`.

Comment: But again, to reiterate the main point in the post: Generics are for *genericizing* your code. If you're trying to get *specific* things from it then just be specific - use overloads, use concrete base classes, etc. When you use a qualified generic it taints everything else because you have to put the same qualifications on everything else it touches.

Comment: for this specific case, i have 50 different UIScreens - each receiving a specific payload in the form of the IScreenController(the chosen name is a bit misleading).

so i kinda of NEED this level of generics, as i want to enforce the specific implementation of IScreenController to a specific Screen.

i do have a solution that is doing Manager.GetScreen<T>().Open(controller) but i wanted to avoid that.

Comment: If you have 50 different UIScreens that need 50 different handlers then you're probably doing it wrong. I've done this in the past and my solution was to force objects that need a UI to draw themselves. Those objects then implement an `IDrawMyself` interface, and then you have one UIScreen script that has `public Canvas Canvas{get; private set;}` and the `IDrawMyself` interface requires drawers to take implement `void Draw(UIScreen uiScreen)`. This is a [visitor pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor/csharp/example) and the UIScreen hands the canvas to the would-be drawers.

Comment: Sorry, but at this point we are just discussing if you think I'm in the wrong or correct path. 

Although i can keep discussing why you are getting it wrong, the matter of the question is if something is possible or not - i have plenty of alternatives if its not possible.

Comment: @MatheusCohen - To answer your question directly, no - if you're not using the types in the input arguments then you have to specify them some other way, and that's through the angle brackets. I can promise you though, if it feels like a struggle there is 100% a better way to do it. I've tried suggesting restructuring your interface, passing parameters to a base class constructor, and using a visitor pattern. These all seem to not suite whatever your use case is but hopefully at least illustrates that there are other ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why

```
public class UIScreen<T> where T : IScreenController
{
  public void Open(T controller) { }
}
```

and not simply

```
public class UIScreen 
{
  public void Open(IScreenController controller) { }
}
```

Comment: because I have many different screens each with a specific screen controller